# What happens if we manually edit ledger of a single-org-single-peer Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have set up the FabCar tutorial network. Will I get some sort of error if I manually edit the ledger and start the Fabric again? Also, I am not able to find the folder /var/hyperledger where the ledger is physically stored. Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FabCar example executed with docker-compose, which mean your peer is running in docker container, consequently to access `/var/hyperledger` you need to log in into your container.

Now to your question:

> Will I get some sort of error if I manually edit the ledger and start the Fabric again?

There are two parts here, there is a ledger which maintains and keep chained block persistent and there is state database.

Now, state database basically represents a latest snapshot of your stated up to last committed block to the ledger. And one of the reasons you need it is to avoid seeking for recent updates in the ledger all the time, but directly access it.

In case you or someone else compromised your peer and changed ledger, w/o touching state, it won't really affect consistency, though you loose the ability to rely on the ledger while doing inspection (audit) on world state. Which could be fixed if you will delete ledger data and make peer to sync from the ordering service or other peers.

Next, if someone forged your peer's world state, you will be able to detect while doing endorsing, meaning with strong enough endorsement policy where you need to confirm execution results with more than one peer eventually you will detect that state has diverged and reply your ledger to recreate a correct one.

There is also a tool which might help you to detect corruptions of your ledger files, please see [here](https://github.com/C0rWin/ledgerfsck).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Instead of world state what if the transaction log was modified in the backend in one of the peers, will that be detected in future consensus?

Comment: What do you mean by transaction log?

Comment: "In case you or someone else compromised your peer and changed ledger, w/o touching state" I missed this earlier. So if the ledger gets modified w/o touching state, there is a chance that the modification would go undetected.

Comment: Unless you scan your ledger for corruptions. Cause even a single bit flip might cause ledger mutation, though it will requires exhaustive scan to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

All ledger, blocks etc stores in below particular location in the peer container

```
/var/hyperledger/production
```

All ledger, blocks etc stores in below particular location in the orderer container

```
/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
```

Coming to your question

> Will I get some sort of error if I manually edit the ledger and start
>   the Fabric again?

I assume that you are using couchdb, you logged in to DB and you 
 edited the ledger which means you changed the world state not the actual chain

When you query it will show updated data, without giving any error (*Terms applicable) we should not do this

Please Never change | tamper the data

Comment: "edited the ledger" while logging into DB you are not changing the ledger by forging the world state. Ledger data stored directly on disk.